# Replacing data in python returns old and new values

Tags: python, regex, string

I am having some issues with the following code:

```
    def string(self):
        vars = []
        string = """
test = "Hello"
print(test)
OK = "Hello"
print(OK)
        """
        pieces = string.split("\n")
        for b in pieces:
            article = re.findall(r'^\s*([^.]*)\b\s*[\+\-\*\/]?\=', b)
            for i in article:
                vars.append(i)

        print(vars)
        for i in vars:
            a = re.sub(f'{i}', f"{(i, self.hash(i)}", string)
            print(a)
            # with open('test.txt', 'a') as fd:
            #     fd.write(f'{a}')
```

Now the result that I currently get is this:

```
XX098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 = "Hello"
print(XX098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6)
OK = "Hello"
print(OK)
        

test = "Hello"
print(test)
XXe0aa021e21dddbd6d8cecec71e9cf564 = "Hello"
print(XXe0aa021e21dddbd6d8cecec71e9cf564)
```

The result I am looking to get is:

```
XX098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 = "Hello"
print(XX098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6)
XXe0aa021e21dddbd6d8cecec71e9cf564 = "Hello"
print(XXe0aa021e21dddbd6d8cecec71e9cf564)
```

thx in advance

Comment: What is your regex supposed to match? Right now, it only matches `test` and `OK` before `=`, no the `OK` in `print(OK)`. See https://regex101.com/r/HiQywu/1

Comment: yes but if was only hoping to get test or OK so I can use string.replace for the rest

Answer (score 0):

You can first extract the vars and then replace the matches as whole words with a single `re.sub` like this:

```py
def string_replace(self):
    text = """test = "Hello"
print(test)
OK = "Hello"
print(OK)"""
    vars = re.findall(r'^\s*(\w+)\b(?=\s*[-+*/]?=)', text, re.M)
    vars = list(set(vars))
    text = re.sub(fr'\b(?:{"|".join(vars)})\b', lambda x: f"{self.hash(x.group())}", text)
    print(text)
```

Here, `^\s*(\w+)\b(?=\s*[-+*/]?=)` [matches](https://regex101.com/r/HiQywu/2)

- `^` - start of a line
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\w+)`- Group 1:
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?=\s*[-+*/]?=)` - after the current position, there must be zero or more whitespaces, a `-`, `+`, `*` or `/` char (optionally) and then a `=` char.

The `vars = list(set(vars))` removes all duplicates in `vars`.

The `re.sub(fr'\b(?:{"|".join(vars)})\b', lambda x: f"{self.hash(x.group())}", text)` replaces all found `vars` as whole words with their hashes.

Note that there is a Python module called `string`, and it is not a good idea to use it as a variable, and at the same time the function name.

See a [full Python demo](https://ideone.com/XcK7aU):

```py
import re
import hashlib


class blah:
    def hash(self, s):
        return  hashlib.md5(s.encode('utf8')).hexdigest()
        
    def string(self):
        text = """test = "Hello"
print(test)
OK = "Hello"
print(OK)"""
        #print(text)
        vars = re.findall(r'^\s*(\w+)\b(?=\s*[-+*/]?=)', text, re.M)
        vars = list(set(vars))
        text = re.sub(fr'\b(?:{"|".join(vars)})\b', lambda x: f"{self.hash(x.group())}", text)
        print(text)
        
        
b = blah()
b.string()
```

Output:

```
098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6 = "Hello"
print(098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6)
e0aa021e21dddbd6d8cecec71e9cf564 = "Hello"
print(e0aa021e21dddbd6d8cecec71e9cf564)
```